# How do I simplify this expression $\exp(xy)-1=\ln\left((x^2+y^2)^{1/2}\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I simplify this expression $\exp(xy)-1=\ln\left((x^2+y^2)^{1/2}\right)$.

I try some ways but could simplify, can you try help me?

Edit: by simplify I mean put y on one side and x on another side?is this possible?

Comment: If the thing on the right is $\ln((x^2+y^2)^{1/2})$, we can rewrite as $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)$, which may look better. However, nothing more suggests itself.

Comment: good clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is simpler at all, and I don't know your use case, but perhaps you can write it in polar coordinates?

By letting

\begin{equation}
x = r \cos(\theta) \\
y = r \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}

and by noting the identity $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, the equation reduces as follows:

\begin{equation}
\exp\left( r^2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) \right) - 1 = \ln(r)
\end{equation}

In fact, one can solve for $\theta$ in terms of $r$ by using the trigonometric identity $\sin(2 \theta) = 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$. The first step towards that is the following:

\begin{equation}
\exp\left( \frac{r^2}{2} \sin(2 \theta) \right) - 1 = \ln(r)
\end{equation}

## Edit:

It is impossible to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. One can observe this by looking at the plot of the equation:

[image: Graph of Equation]

Comment: Good. That is what I was planning to write as well.

Comment: @Mohith thanks solving for teta in respect to r you got an expression with separable variables however back sub x and y you turn out with x and y on both sides, ... however you can determine x and using the relation between r and teta

Comment: @Mohith this has to do with interception of surfaces and I was trying to see the set of points where the planes intersect

Comment: By the way sorry not give thumbs up I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

$$\exp(xy) = (1/2) \log(x^2 + y^2) + 1$$

Are you looking for this?

Comment: No I am looking for an expression with y on on side and x on another. But if that was the case it was pointless post the question. @mike

Comment: By other words how I join y with y and x with x? It is possible or not possible?

Comment: @KellyBlunie. Do not shoot the messenger. ;-) I am just trying to make your problem and this answer contain less ambiguity.

Comment: @mike OK. Do you have any idea how I could solve for y, I try logarithmic exponentials different approaches , I run out of ideas

Comment: @gragas any ideas how could I solve for y?

Comment: @KellyBlunie. Mohith's approach may work for you!

Comment: @KellyBlunie I believe that this problem is not solvable for "y on one side and x on the other."